# How add a colored top left curved triangle in an ion item in ionic 3

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

[image]

Hi, I want to add a colored triangular curve on the top left of my ion item. My ion item contains an image and a label. So far I have been able to get the below style. When I try to adjust the image, the triangular curve disappears. Below is my code for HTML and CSS.

```
<ion-item no-lines>
  <div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
  <img src="{{item.img}}">
   {{item.label}}
</ion-item>

.item{
    padding: 8px;
    // border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px 50px 30px !important;
    // border-radius: 15px 50px !important;
    // border-radius: 15px 50px 30px 5px !important;
    text-align: center;
    width: calc(50% - 5px);
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: color($colors,primary);
    height: 130px;
    box-shadow: -5px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    &.active-item{
       color: color($colors,third); 
    }
    &:nth-child(2n){
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    &:nth-child(2n + 1){
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    #triangle-topleft {
        width: 0.1em;
        height: 0.1em;
        border-top: 100px solid color($colors,primary);;
        border-right: 100px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 20% 20% 20% 53%;
        transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-42.3%) 
        skewX(30deg) scaleY(.866) translateX(-24%);
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    img{
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        object-fit: contain;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .item-inner{
        padding: 0;
        .label{
            margin: 0;
            white-space:unset;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This might be more easily achieved using a pseudo element with a blue background and a clip-path or with a radial-gradient background-image rather than trying to get borders to behave as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a colored rectangle to the top left corner and cut out the desired shape with [clip-path](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)